# Get Windows App Version number

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, win-universal-app, winjs

**Hello**,
how can i get a Windows App version number using WINJS?

```
<div id="version"></div>
```

i tried this code, but seems not working

```
var thisPackage = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current;
var version = thisPackage.id.version;

var appVersion = version.major + "." +
                 version.minor + "." +
                 version.build + "." +
                 version.revision;

document.getElementById("version").innerHTML = appVersion;
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no error in your posted code. It works well in my side. You can try with the official [App package information sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Package). In **scenario1_identity.js**, it uses similar code to get the app version.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I think you should post this as an answer... I just came across it while trying to find out how to do this the code snippet worked perfectly for me.